# Retract Binary file in resx

Tags: c#, resx

I have read all posts on Resource file, but most of all are talking about getting string. I have two binary files in resx file named myRes.resx. How to retract them and save to disk?

```html
<resheader name="resmimetype"><value>text/microsoft-resx</value></resheader><resheader name="version"><value>1.3</value></resheader><resheader name="reader"><value>System.Resources.ResXResourceReader, System.Windows.Forms, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b99a5c561934e000</value></resheader><resheader name="writer"><value>System.Resources.ResXResourceWriter, System.Windows.Forms, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b99a5c561934e000</value></resheader><data name="7zip.dll" type="System.Byte[], mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b99a5c561934e000"><value>

TVqQAAMAAAAEAAAA//8AALgAAAAAAAAAQAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA
 gAAAAA4fug4AtAnNIbgBTM0hVGhpcyBwcm9ncmFtIGNhbm5vdCBiZSBydW4gaW4gRE9TIG1vZGUuDQ0K
 JAAAAAAAAABQRQAATAEDALtch0YAAAAAAAAAAOAADiELAQYAANAAAAAgAAAAAAAA7ugAAAAgAAAAAAEA

......
</value>
```

```
rm = new ResourceManager("MyTestApp.myRes.resources", Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());
byte[] array = null;
array = (byte[])rm.GetObject("7zip.dll");  //error
```

Comment: It looks like you save the data as text. It looks like a 64 base string.  So use Convert From 64 base string.

Comment: I missed that. Now I got them.